# How should this be read?

Tags: grammar, sentence, meaning

> We all know that you do not belong here, have no idea what you are talking about, and can't actually script.

Should this be interpreted as

> 1. We all know that you do not belong here
> 2. You have no idea what you are talking about
> 3. You can't actually script

Or

> 1. We all know that you do not belong here
> 2. We have no idea what you are talking about
> 3. We can't actually script

And why?

Comment: I think your original quote is wrong using "We" in becoming the first sentence. In fact, it should be "They". So the correct version is "*They* all know that you do not belong here, *we* have no idea what you are talking about, and *you* can't actually script." Suggestion: If you use all the pronuns it is likely you got at least one.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, both interpretations are possible. If you want to be *really* pedantic*, you could add the possibility that it might mean ***we** can't script*. But these are perverse interpretations, given that the first of the three "attributive clauses" unambiguously refers to ***you***. I think this is either Not Constructive, or a duplicate of [How to determine what an attributive clause modifies](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32783/) (to which the answer is "by using logic, not grammar").

Comment: "Me" being part of "We" makes "They" seem like I am not included, which is necessary to be made clear. That also does not solve the potential confusion. We belong here, you do not; both we and you have no idea what you are talking about; you do not belong here, and we do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string of words which is distributed across all three clauses must be either

> **We all** or
>   **We all know that you**

since only these two strings provide a single subject for the verbs *have* and *can*. The natural parse is that it is the longer string. That would define these as the three underlying propositions:

> We all know that you do not belong here.
>   [We all know that you] have no idea what you are talking about.
>   [We all know that you] can't actually script.

*We all* is possible but unlikely, since *We all don't know what you're talking about* and *We all can't script* are only marginally idiomatic: most people would say *None of us know what you're talking about* and *None of us can script*.

Comment: +1 Moreover, there can be no doubt that the speakers intend to deprecate "you", not themselves.